# How to make a bash script run for a limited time, but not kill the process immediately?

Tags: bash, shell, timeout

I'm not sure if this has been asked before, but if I have a script that runs an infinite loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
        echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."
        sleep 1
done
```

and I want to run it for 10 seconds only, but I don't want it to stop right away, for example, in psudo code, I want something like this:

```
while true:
    if 10 seconds elapsed:
       do something
       then kill

    else
      keep going #this takes an arbitrary amount of time
```

I tried gtimeout, and it does kill the process after a certain period of time, but my problem is that the inner loop does not know about how much time has passed. Is there anything I can add into the script itself to achieve that?

Thank you!

Comment: So you want a watchdog functionality that will kill the script if it goes 10 seconds without signalling that it's ok?

Comment: no, I simply want the loop, which will execute some commands, to run repeatedly for a certain period of time, and then execute something else before the time runs out. So I want the inner loop to know about the time. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but can you perhaps use the `$SECONDS` variable? It counts up from when the shell was started, and can be reset to 0 any time you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NUM_SECS_TO_RUN=605 # Time you want to run for in seconds, 1 day would be 84600

TIME_NOW=$( date +"%H:%M:%S" )

END_TIME=$( date -d "${TIME_NOW} today + ${NUM_SECS_TO_RUN} seconds" +"%y%m%d%H%M%S" )

echo "Starting" $(date)

while [ $( date +"%y%m%d%H%M%S" ) -lt ${END_TIME} ]
do
   # whatever it is that you want to do repeatedly until the period expires
   do_something 
done

echo "Expired" $(date)
do_something_at_end # whatever it is you want to do right at the end
echo "FInished" $(date)
```

A couple of thing:

- The idea above is simply to convert the expiry time and the current time to number to make the comparison easier
- It seems you want to loop and do_Something, and then when the time expires do something at the end then exit the loop. I have put the "do_Something_at_end" outside the timed loop.
- If "do_Something" is a long running process, and might take longer than required, consider running it as a background job, then have a "sleep ${MAX_TIME_ALLOWED}" after which "kill " it.
- You could put something inside "do_something" to check for run time limit to ensure each run does not overrun, but that would require detailed knowledge of what that script does.

Answer (score 0):

```
for t in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ; do
    if [ $t -eq 9 ] ; then
        #do something
        kill
        break
    fi
    echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."
    sleep 1
done
# keep going
```

Run for 24 hours, checking every second (note I took the prompt out of the loop, so it doesn't have to echo 86400 times):

```
t=0
echo "Press [CTRL+C] to stop.."
while true ; do
    if [ $t -eq 86400 ] ; then
        #do something
        kill
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
    t=$(( t + 1 ))
done
# keep going
```

Comment: okay, that looks great, but what if I want to run for 24 hrs?

Comment: okay, I'm not sure this works though, because this: #keep going, may take much more than 1 second. It's not instant. – Lana 18 mins ago

Comment: I'm really not sure I understand the problem.